# Can pthread_create() thread-ID of detached thread be ephemeral on the stack?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

Is it conforming for the thread-ID argument of the `pthread_create()` function to be on the stack if the thread is detached? For example

```
void func()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, start_func, NULL);
    pthread_detach(thread);
}
```

Or will the disappearance of the thread-ID variable cause problems? I've read the standard and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: @this, The answer is the same but I'd argue that the nature of the question is different.

Comment: @merlin2011 Don't be afraid of the `Close button`.

Comment: @this, I have closed a few questions which are true duplicates. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6467322/391161) to a related question, I would say it is safe even if you do not use `pthread_detach`.

Since you will not be trying to `join` it in the future, there's no reason you need to keep it around.